# How to cache HTMLElement.focus in a variable?

Tags: javascript, dom, function-binding

What is the correct context to store the `focus` function of an HTMLElement in a variable?

I tried,

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
var focus = elem.focus.bind(document); // focus() Illegal Invocation
var focus2 = elem.focus.bind(elem); // focus2() Illegal Invocation
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into your own function:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
var focusElem = function(){ elem.focus(); };
focusElem();
```